# How can I combine multiple same functionality classes (controllers) into one that takes a data object as a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have coded methods looking like this:

```
var result = await db.TaskStatuses
     .Select(e => new
     {
         Id = e.TaskStatusId,
         Name = e.Name
     })
     .ToListAsync();
```

and

```
var result = await db.ContentStatuses
         .Select(e => new
         {
             Id = e.ContentStatusId,
             Name = e.Name
         })
         .ToListAsync();

var result = await db.<xxx>
         .Select(e => new
         {
             Id = e.<xxx>Id,
             Name = e.Name
         })
         .ToListAsync();
```

All the methods are the same except for the database object they get data from. Is there a way that I could combine all these into one method where I just pass in the object as a parameter?

Here's how db is created:

```
private myContext db = new MyContext();

 public partial class MyContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<TaskStatuse> TaskStatuses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ContentStatuses> ContentStatuses { get; set; }
```

Here's the full code of a controller (Asp.Net Web-API):

```
namespace WebRole1.Controllers
{

    [Route("api/ContentStatus/{id?}", Name = "api_ContentStatus")]
    public class ContentStatusController : ApiController
    {
        private MyContext db = new MyContext();

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMapData()
        {
            var result = await db.ContentStatuses
                                 .Select(e => new
                                 {
                                     Id = e.ContentStatusId,
                                     Name = e.Name
                                 })
                                 .ToListAsync();
            return Ok(result);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }
}
```

My problem is I have many of these controllers and they are all the same except for the data source. ContentStatus, TaskStatus etc.

Sample classes:

```
public class ContentStatus
{
    public ContentStatus()
    {
        this.Contents = new List<Content>();
    }

    public int ContentStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}

public class TaskStatus
{
    public TaskStatus()
    {
        this.Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }

    public int TaskStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How does one **`taxes`** a parameter?

Comment: It is possible to do this using reflection, but it would probably be better if you made an interface that exposes `Id` and `Name` properties and made all your `ContentStatus`, `TaskStatus` etc. classes implement it. Then you could just write a single method that takes an ienumerable of that interface.

Comment: @Asad while good idea it may not work if classes are generated in some way (likely as it looks like code directly reading from DB)...

Comment: I added some more information to the question. I hope this makes it more clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are using `EntityFramework`, T4 generates partial classes which makes it easy for you to implement a common interface for those `Entities` as Asad mentioned.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The classes appear to be entities used as part of an Entity Framework ORM setup. It is entirely possible to make these classes implement interfaces, since the proxy classes generated by EF derive from the user's own POCO classes.

Comment: @Asad post it as answer than since it would work for OP.

Comment: @Asad - I added some more details and showed an example controller. Hope you can use this as a source for an answer if you think you have a good way to solve my problem. Thanks very much.

Comment: @marifemac I'd need to see the `TaskStatus` and `ContentStatus` classes in order to show you an example of the interface I'm talking about. That said, it shouldn't be too hard to do this yourself. Just create an interface with `Id` and `Name` properties corresponding to the values you want to retrieve, and make `TaskStatus` and `ContentStatus` implement the interface explicitly.

Comment: I will add these now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a common interface for your classes that exposes the properties you need in your methods. You can then consume this interface in a single method that can deal with items of either type

```
public interface IIdentifiableStatus
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}

public class ContentStatus : IIdentifiableStatus
{
    public ContentStatus()
    {
        this.Contents = new List<Content>();
    }

    public int ContentStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }

    int IIdentifiable.Id
    {
        get { return ContentStatusId; }
    }

    string IIdentifiable.Name
    {
        get { return Name; }
    }
}

public class TaskStatus : IIdentifiableStatus
{
    public TaskStatus()
    {
        this.Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }

    public int TaskStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    int IIdentifiable.Id
    {
        get { return TaskStatusId; }
    }

    string IIdentifiable.Name
    {
        get { return Name; }
    }
}
```

Your method would then look like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMapData(IEnumerable<IIdentifiableStatus> statuses)
{
    var result = await statuses
        .Select(e => new {
            Id = e.Id,
            Name = e.Name
        })
        .ToListAsync();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

You could call the method like so:

```
GetMapData(db.ContentStatuses)
```

or:

```
GetMapData(db.TaskStatuses)
```